# Навигация по разным листам книги Excel в VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в VBA считывать данные из ячеек одного листа, а вставлять их в ячейки другого листа? Варианты с формулами не предлагать, поскольку требуется именно через VBA

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub switch()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Лист1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Лист2")

    ' индексация ячеек начинается с 1 в формате (номер строки, номер столбца)
    ' скопирует данные с первого листа ячейки A1 на второй лист в ячейку A1
    ws2.Cells(1, 1) = ws1.Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста: по какому событию считывать? Достаточно кнопки для запуска макроса? Копировать диапазон или ячейку? Если большими диапазонами, с перестановкой или выборкой, лучше использовать массивы: считать исходные данные в память, обработать, выгрузить на лист.